# How can I specify a custom Cargo output directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I put this in my Cargo.toml

```
[build]
target-dir = "../my-target"
```

However, Cargo doesn't recognize this key.

```
cargo run --release --bin my_project

warning: unused manifest key: build
error: failed to open: /.../project-root/target/releases/.cargo-lock

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

The custom target dir with the environment variable works:

```
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=../my-target cargo run --bin my_project
```

but how can I specify '../my-target' in Cargo.toml?

Comment: Where is the default directory, i cant find the build output of cargo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`[build]` is a [Cargo-level configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) rather than for the project:

> This document will explain how Cargo’s configuration system works, as well as available keys or configuration. For configuration of a project through its manifest, see the manifest format.

Put your `[build]` inside `$PROJECT_DIR/.cargo/config.toml` or even `$HOME/.cargo/config.toml`. See the above link for all the options.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [`CARGO_TARGET_DIR` environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads):

```
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=../my-target cargo run --bin my_project
```

(This is stated in the question, but I wanted to highlight it for anyone that skips over that)

Comment: This works very well in `Makefile` if you specify some `RUSTFLAGS` value there, since changing `RUSTFLAGS` value invalidates the compiled cache -- unless it's stored in a separate folder.

Answer (score 4):

Besides setting the [`CARGO_TARGET_DIR` environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads) or the [`build.target-dir` setting in `/.cargo/config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildtarget-dir), Cargo also has the [`--target-dir` CLI option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html#output-options) for specifying the target directory.